# Three phase AC power measurement

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, electrical, efficiency, power-measurement

I am trying to measure the output power for BLDC controller, in order to calculate the efficiency of the controller. I came to know that two watt-meter method is one of the method used to calculate the three phase AC power.

[image]

But instead of using two wattmeters, i have.....

- Two clamp meters (AC/DC clamp meter) for measuring I<sub>r</sub> and I<sub>Y</sub>.
- Two multimeters (AC/DC) for measuring V<sub>RB</sub> and V<sub>YB</sub>.
- My input power is DC 48 volt. P = V × I will give me the input power.
- But to calculate the output power has complexity.

W1 = I<sub>R</sub> × V<sub>RB</sub>  and  W2 = I<sub>Y</sub> × V<sub>YB</sub>

W1 + W2 gives the output power.

***For voltage measurement V<sub>RB</sub> and V<sub>YB</sub>:***

My bldc controller output is trapezoidal waveform with variable output frequency, Vrb and Vyb can be calculated by using ac multi meter. Because ac voltage does not depends on the Frequency, whatever the Output frequency the Vrms will be the same i guess. Correct me friends if i am wrong.

***For current measurement Ir and Iy :***
Since the AC current must not be same for different frequency at all time. How to calculate the AC current at my output frequency say (eg: 100 Hz).

Edited...
Sorry i forgot to say something, I am driving the bldc controller with bldc motor in a load setup.

Comment: I've fixed some of the random and missing capitalisation and shown how to write subscripts (`<sub>...</sub>`) but ran out of energy to finish them all.

Answer (score 1):

To measure power in the situation shown, the instrumentation system must be able to determine the instantaneous values of voltage and current, multiply current X voltage at corresponding instants and integrate the results over the period of the waveform. You can not measure the power using the instrumentation described.

Answer (score 1):

You can always figure out real power taking all the points that make up the the instantaneous power of an element: \$v(t)i(t)\$ and averaging them out over some time interval to get

\$\displaystyle P_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{i}^{i+T} v(t)i(t)dt =\frac{1}{T}\sum_T v(t)i(t)\$

If you only have RMS meters then you have to sit down with your theoretical waveform and calculate it out real power analytically, then RMS analytically, and then compare the two to know the appropriate fudge factor to apply to your RMS numbers so that you can adjust the numbers from your meter. But phase and waveform shape cannot change from your theoretical or it will throw things off. That is to say, there is no real way to do it with just RMS meters since they do not retain the phase information.

Comment: Then what is the way to find the efficiency of the bldc controller.

Comment: @Bud You need equipment suitable for the task. The other way is to apply a known load to the motor or measure the torque, and measure its RPM to measure the mechanical output power directly.

Comment: ALthough, I suppose that if you just use a Y-resistive load instead of a motor there will be no phase shifts. In that case, you could measure the output power of the BLDC controller with RMS meters but you would have to rig it so it actually runs without an actual motor there (fake commutation signals). That will get you some gauge on efficiency, but since there will be no flyback since no inductance then it won't be exactly the same as if a motor were there. Certainly it won't let you find any inefficiencies due to commutation.

Comment: What equipment and method are required to calculate or find the bldc controller efficiency.

Comment: @Bud You either need a three-phase power meter (which is probably too expensive and specific), or an oscilloscope with one voltage probe and one current probe if you assume balanced phases. Preferably you would have three voltage probes and three current probes and a 6 channel scope, but that's asking for a lot. Instead of current probe, you could use a current sense resistor and differential probe. You would use the multiplication and averaging function of the scope to calculate average instantaneous power

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen for the response.Does the three phase power meter works for our application (bldc motor) . Because the output will be 30 - 40 volt ac and 30 amp ac with different output frequency in each phase.

Comment: "https://www.vpinstruments.com/download/135/manual-3-phase-power-meter/1oNObMuH4OXXdiulTZDXQiVEtScjDsvIz/Manual%203%20Phase%20Power%20Meter"  This is 3 a phase power meter but it works only at 220v and 50-60hz. But my application outputs 40v ac and at  different frequency. Which one will be suits for my application.

Comment: "https://e2e.ti.com/resized-image/__size/800x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-07-88/2248.f4.jpg" Could anyone explain it breifly how to calculate the winding current.

Comment: @Bud If it's the kind of 3-phase meter that doesn't assume anything about the waveform it will.